# Passing a Parameter to ViewModel constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Is it possible to pass a parameter to the ViewModel constructor? I would then use this parameter to initialise a property and/or do other operations in the ViewModel.

With WinForms I could do

```
public MyForm(MyParamType myParam) {
    MyFormProperty = myParam;
    //etc.
}
```

How do I go about doing something similar in the MVVM pattern / using MVVM Light?

Any suggestions would be most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many thanks to all who've answered. As a temporary solution I've done something like, `((MyViewModel)MyView.DataContext).MyProperty = myParam; ` -- However, will be using an IoC container to handle this eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using an IoC container and configuring your container to supply the parameter upon construction.

For instance, here's what a typical code-behind to a UserControl looks like for me in WPF:

```
public partial class MyDataGridView : IMyListView
{
    public MyDataGridView()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyDataGridView(MyListViewModel viewModel)
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      DataContext = viewModel;
 }
}
```

StructureMap creates the MyListViewModel for me because by default it searches for the greediest constructor and then provides the dependencies. In my StructureMap configuration, I can specify that the MyListViewModel be provided with whatever parameters are necessary upon construction of that object.

With a container like StructureMap, I don't have to "new" up objects. Ever.

Comment: Upvoted for suggesting dependency injection.  DI makes for a much more unit-testable application.

Comment: Thanks, dependency injection is probably the most sustainable way to go forward. I have a bit of refactoring to do once I've shopped around and decide which IoC container to use.

Comment: @lazo - last time I shopped around I found that liked Ninject for IoC the best but in application ran into problems deciding the best way to share the Kernel.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MVVM light (even if you're not I guess) you could register a message handler with the Messenger that takes your constructor parameters (or a tuple thereof) and updates the VM whenever you need to "reconstruct" it.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the view models are static on the locator, you can just access those properties already without changing a constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I ended up doing something similar to what you suggest here as a short-term solution.

Answer (score -1):

I dont understand why you cant just create the viewmodel yourself. You can always create your own viewmodel. If there is a viewmodel provided by MVVM Light then you can always inherit from that one and create an overloaded constructor.